# oAuth login to google script from android

Tags: android, oauth, google-apps-script, google-api

I have been trying hard to find some resources wherein I can get the google script which has "anyone" permission and running with "user accessing the web app" permission,i.e. it requires one to be logged in with his gmail account to be callable from android.

How do I authenticate to the script in such cases. The script just reads few rows from spreadsheet and renders JSON response?

Answer (score 0):

An Android app (as any other web app) that needs to access any resource protected by a Google Apps account should use the [Google Authentication Service](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForWebApps).

If you're developing in Java, [Google's OAuth library is in Beta](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2#Android) for Android. The authorization flow is described in the [same document](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2#Authorization_Code_Flow).

Once you've obtained an access token, your app can make requests to the GAS app with it.